# Finding the symmetry of points?

Tags: geometry

The points $p=(a,b,c)$ and $q=(2,3,5)$ are symmetric in the sense given.

About the plain $y=-1$.

I have to find abc

I am not sure how to solve this I ,know $y=-1$ makes a plane that keep extending because $x,z$ are not named.

My second question is like the first except about the point $(0,2,1)$.

I am not sure what this question is trying to tell...

Comment: yes I get it it is (0,1,0) in the triple point

Comment: sorry, I missreadyour question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plane $y=-1$ is all points for which $y = -1$.  You noticed that $x,z$ do not appear here, which is good.  The values $x,z$ can be anything.  All of them lie in the plane $y=-1$.

Let's describe the point symmetric to $q = (2,3,5)$ about the plane $y=-1$.  Point $q$ is some distance from the plane.  The point $p$ will be on the other side of the plane, the same distance from the plane.  The values of $x$ and $z$ don't change -- just the $y$ value.

Or more generally, the image $p$ of the point $q$ with respect to a plane will be the point that is (a) the same distance from the plane as $q$, and (b) colinear with the normal (perpendicular) line to the plane that passes through $q$.

The distance of $q$ from the plane $y=-1$ is $3 - (-1) = 4$.  The other value of $y$ that is a distance of $4$ away from $-1$ is $-5$.

So your image is $p=(3,-5,5)$.

You can find the image of $(0,2,1)$ the same way.

Comment: I see that makes sense thanks